# Exchange data between jenkins agents

Tags: java, jenkins, agent, remoting

I am working on a jenkins project.

I want each agent, through java, to send an Id to all others jenkins agents.
They will receive as many numbers as agents and save them in a text file.
Is it possible to implement this?

If not, is there a way to manage the communication between the agents to be able to exchange data.

I tried to use Computer, Channel, Callable and Jenkins class but it seems that this is not helping